# Using MarkupExtension to display images in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, markup

I have a Resource (.resx) with a log of svg images in it. Furthermore I use an ImageResource class that can take the byte[] provided by the resource and convert it into an ImageSource Object. 
While doing that, I have the possibility to Change the color of the Icon

```
ImageResource.CreateFromSvg(image, Brushes.Green);
```

I was searching for an easy way to get these Images into xaml, so I created another static class that creates an Image using the ImageResource class. In xaml I could use

```
<Image Source={x:Static img:ImageResources.MyGreenIcon}/>
```

to get the icon. The downside was, that I was not able to choose the color in xaml. So I tried and created a **MarkupExtension** for that. It takes a **byte[]** and a **Brush** as parameters, calls the *CreateFromSvg*-Method and returns the Image. In Xaml it looks like this

```
<Image Source={i:Img {x:Static img:SvgResources.TheIcon}, Green}/>
```

Where SvgResources is the .resx-file the Image is in.
Although this works well, I was not able to change the color at runtime. Because MarkupExtension is not a DependencyProperty I can not use a binding for the color. I tried to use a trigger

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{i:Img {x:Static img:SvgResources.TheIcon}, Blue}" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This does not give any error, but just do nothing. So my questions are

1. How can I reassign the Source of the Image to get another color
2. Is there a way to use something like a binding to change the color from VM
3. Is there a way to shorten the `{x:Static img:SvgResources.TheIcon` to something like `svgResource.TheIcon`

**Edit**

I found out, that the Trigger does change the Source if I don't set the source in the control itself, but instead provide a default value in the trigger (IsMouseOver = false). Questions 2 + 3 still remain

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 2.

You can extend your `MarkupExtension` to support `Binding` with `MultiValueConverter`.

Create simple MultiValueConverter, which will simply call your `ImageResource.CreateFromSvg(...);`. Values passed to this converter will be image and `Brush`  (static image or brush resolved from Bindings)

In `ProvideValue(...)` detect is passed value `Brush` or `Binding`. If it's `Brush` create mock `Binding` for it with this `Brush` as `Source`.
If value is `Binding` - we will use it. Do same for image

Create `Multibinding`, assign just created `MultiValueConverter` and add image and brush bindings.

`return` provided value.

Complete example of Img MarkupExtension:

```
public class Img : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly object _image;
    private readonly object _brush;
    public Img(object image, object brush)
    {
        _image = image;
        _brush = brush;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var imageBinding = _image is Binding iBinding ? iBinding : new Binding { Source = _image};
        var brushBinding = _brush is Binding bBinding ? bBinding : new Binding { Source = _brush };

        var binding = new MultiBinding
        {
            Converter = new ImgValueConverter()
        };

        binding.Bindings.Add(imageBinding);
        binding.Bindings.Add(brushBinding);

        return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }

    private class ImgValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var image = values[0];
            var brush = values[1];

            return ImageResource.CreateFromSvg(image, brush);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
        <Image Source="{i:Img {x:Static i:SvgResources.TheIcon}, {x:Static Brushes.Yellow}}"/>
        <Image Source="{i:Img {x:Static i:SvgResources.TheIcon}, {Binding Brush}}"/>
```